# extjs 4 removing node from treepanel giving error in custom drag and drop

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop, treeview, extjs4, treepanel

I am setting up a custom drag and drop implementation with treepanels, where I want all nodes to attach to a node I have created under the root. I am trying to drag one node from one treepanel to the other in a certain way. I am able to move the item over, but run into trouble when removing it from the other side.

Here is my code, this is within my treepanel:

```
viewConfig:{
 plugins:{
  ptype:'treeviewdragdrop',
  DDgroup:'treeDD'
 },

 listeners:{
    beforedrop: function(node, data, dropRec, dropPosition){
      if(dropRec.parentNode.data.text == "Root"){
        console.log('dropping on top level');
        this.up('panel').getStore().getRootNode().getChildAt(0).insertChild(0, data.records[0].data);
        //the below line seems to be causing the error, how should I be removing?
        choicesTree.getRootNode().getChildAt(0).removeChild(data.records[0]);
        //choicesTree is previously defined
        return false;
      }
}
```

This manages to removed the item from the first treepanel, but immediatly gives the following error:

```
item is null
fly(item.firstChild).highlight(me.repairHighlightColor, {
```

Comment: From the documentation: Returning false to this event signals that the drop gesture was invalid, and if the drag proxy will animate back to the point from which the drag began.

Returning 0 To this event signals that the data transfer operation should not take place, but that the gesture was valid, and that the repair operation should not take place.

Any other return value continues with the data transfer operation.

Comment: If I return 0, I don't get the error. However, returning 0 doesn't work how the docs say, it does transfer data, and in a way I don't want...

Comment: What is the best way to work around this as it looks like the docs are incorrect?

Comment: Two questions: 1) Why do with `insertChild()` you add `.data` and not the `NodeInterace` itself (`data.records[0]`). 2) `getChildAt(0).removeChild(data.records[0])` kind of means that the user will always drag from the first child of the root node - is this what you have in mind?

Comment: Regardless, it is safer to remove child nodes by getting the parent from the removed node and then remove the child from its parent. (`parent = child.parent; parent.removeChild(child);`).

Comment: data.records[0] is the first node that is in the drag object, correct? It is not the first child of the root node.

Comment: Yes, but `getRootNode().getChildAt(0)` means the first child of the root node. Who said `data.records[0]` will always be a child of that first child?

Comment: I said that. The treepanel I am dragging from has the root, one node under the root, and then all other items are children of that. I want the same setup in the treepanel I am dragging to. So, I am making all the nodes a child of a particular node. That's what makes this hard.... I want the nodes to go under a child of root, otherwise I would just use a grid.

Comment: I don't think that has any hand in the error though. I'm confused as to why, when I try to remove the node from the source treepanel, I get that error... I think it has something to do with returning false, but I don't know

Comment: The returning false could be the issue, you can easily check if you set a breakpoint on the preceding removal line (or just put `console.log()` before the return false. Do you still get the error, or do you get it after returning false?

Comment: Could you please have a look at [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/U7h3r/1/)? I don't get an error.

Comment: I'll edit the fiddle in a moment to better represent my setup

Comment: I'm actually having an issue reproducing my error in the fiddle. I'm using 4.07 while that is using 4.1, that could make a difference

Comment: Yes. As [this updated 4.07 JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/U7h3r/8/) shows - it throws an error. The Tree package had a lot of issues with 4.0.7; They solved many bugs in 4.1; I'd recommend upgrading.

Comment: Upgrading is not an option for me at this point.... I'll have to find a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return false is causing the issue in the code. return 0 also doesn't work as the docs describe. The code is not working due to bugs in version 4.07 of extjs the code works as expected in version 4.1

From the documentation: Returning false to this event signals that the drop gesture was invalid, and if the drag proxy will animate back to the point from which the drag began. Returning 0 To this event signals that the data transfer operation should not take place, but that the gesture was valid, and that the repair operation should not take place. Any other return value continues with the data transfer operation.

The above behavior from the docs is different from what occurs